# Overwrite certain values in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, overwrite

I have this piece of code:

```
for (int z = 0; z < date1Index.Length; z++)
{
    test[date1Index[z]] = datA_new[date2Index[z]]; 
}
```

My Problem: 
I have four arrays : `datE_old` and `datA_old` have length 840. `datE_new` and `datA_new` have length 20. Now I looped through the `datE` arrays and checked if a date sequence is equal and stored the index values into `date1Index` (10 Index Values (integers) from 829 till 839)  and `date2Index` (also 11 values from 0 till 10). So at this indexes the dates are the same. Now I copied the `datA_old` array into a new one called test. What I now want to do is the following: I want to replace the values from the `test` array at the indexes 829 till 839 with the values from the `datA_new` array at the indexes 0-9 but I get an `OutOfBoundException`. What is wrong?

That's the code were I store the Index etc:

```
test = datA_old;

for (int c = 0; c < datE_new.Length; c++)
{
    for (int d = 0; d < datE_old.Length; d++)
    {
        if (datE_new[c] == datE_old[d])
        {
            s_dateold.Add(c);
            s_datenew.Add(d);
        }
    }
}

date1Index = s_dateold.ToArray();
date2Index = s_datenew.ToArray();
```

Comment: what length is your `test` array?

Comment: please Show us the code of the operations you mentioned.

Comment: Because I copied the datA_old array into it: Length is 840

Comment: There is no problem with provided code, probably because it is very short. If you want us to find the problem we need more code.

Comment: can you debug and tell us the value range within `date1Index` and `date1Index`?

Comment: He shows me an error at test[date1Index[z]] = datA_new[date2Index[z]]; - how can I see more details?

Comment: date2Index is the problem. There is somehow the value 830 in it

Answer (score 0):

So you want to replace the values of test[829],test[830],....,test[839] with the values _data_new[0],_data_new[1],...,_data_new[9].

If that's exactly what you wish to accomplish then you should change the loop like this:

```
for(int z = 0; z < 10; z++)
{
     test[829+z] = _data_new[z];
}
```

Also pay attention that the indexed from 829 to 839 are not 10 values but 11, if both index values are included, you cannot copy 10 values (0-9) to 11 places (829-839)

Comment: Thats just the example. The index values can change. So its dynamicly. He stores the index values into the arrays date1Index and date2Index so I have to take the values from these arrays and use them as index values which are getting replaced - It was my fault - I have edited that now to 11 values

Comment: In the new code that you posted, there is this statement: test = datA_old;
Now this does not copy datA_old to test, it just copies the references. You don't have two separate arrays with the same data, you have two references pointing to the same array.

Since the operation that you are trying to complete is a bit complex, consider using a list. You can also grab the values you want using a LINQ query

Answer (score 0):

Solved it: The line

```
test[date1Index[z]] = datA_new[date2Index[z]];
```

had to be changed to:

```
test[date2Index[z]] = datA_new[date1Index[z]];
```